# Error implementing a Weighted Graphs class in java

Tags: java, graph, error-handling, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a java class to implement wheighted graphs.
But I get the NullPointerException error in nodes.add(a) of the constructor.

```
public class WGraph {
public ArrayList<Node> nodes;

public WGraph(int n) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        Node a = new Node(i);
        nodes.add(a);
    }

}
```

The class Node and in particular the Node(int key) constructor are defined as follows:

```
public class Node {
public int key;
public ArrayList<Edges> connections;


public Node(int key) {
    this.key=key;
    this.connections = new ArrayList<Edges>();
```

When I run

```
WGraph o = new WGraph(3);


System.out.println(o);
```

I get the NullPointerException error and I have no ideia why.

Comment: `public ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();` should solve your issue

Comment: It did! Thank you